# Construct a non-increasing sequence (An) such that it converges to its supremum.

Tags: convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

We know that a real sequence which is increasing and bounded above converges to its supremum. Is this possible for a non - increasing sequence as well? State that sequence.
I am not able to think of a suitable example for this. Please help me.

Comment: Hint:  Consider two sequences which both increase to $1$ but at different speeds, and then alternate between them.

Comment: We know .5. .2, .05, .02 ... is decreasing and converges to 0. What about .5, .05, .2, .02, .005, .0005, .002, .0002, ... . Does this help?

Comment: Do you really mean *non-increasing,*,i.e. $\forall n,x_{n+1}\le x_n?$ Or do you rather mean *not increasing* i.e. $\exists n,x_{n+1}<x_n?$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_calculus_and_analysis

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $A_{n}$ with $A_{2n-1} = 5$, $A_{2n} = 5 - \frac{1}{n}$, this is a non-increasing sequence and it converge to it suprem $5$